# How to formatting code blocks in R blogdown (RMarkdown)

Tags: python, r-markdown, blogdown

I am using the theme at https://github.com/laozhu/hugo-nuo

I was trying to include python code (it doesn't matter eval=TRUE or FALSE to me) in RMarkdown file for post. The output file is complied as a post by R blogdown (html). However, the formatting is not very reader friendly (plain text). I am wondering if there is any way to format the code blocks? (different color, bold, italic or add a blank line between codes?) Thank you.

````
```{python eval=FALSE}

```
````

[image]

Comment: Your question is very broad: there are many means to format code blocks in `Rmarkdown`. Please, could you add your output format in the question (`html_document`, `pdf_document` or other) because answers depend on the output format?

Comment: Thanks. I just added html in my post.

Comment: If this is HTML, then the question you should be asking is "where is the CSS?"

Comment: @W_17 Have you read [this appendix](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/website-basics.html) of the `blogdown` documentation? As @usr2564301 says, all the `HTML` formatting is in the `CSS` (and sometimes in the `JS` scripts too). It depends on the `Hugo` theme you choose: could you add the theme that you use in your question?

Comment: @romles Thank you for reply. I just added my theme in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default blogdown theme (as well as several other hugo themes) use [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) which allows you to highlight code in 176 languages (including Python).

That said, it seems to me that the theme you are using does not. You need to:

1. Download [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)
2. Save the `highlight.pack.js` into *themes/hugo-nuo/static/js*
3. Copy the css format you like (these are the color options) into *themes/hugo-nuo/static/css*
4. On the `header.html` or `head.html` file (depending which one is the one that links files) write the following and change "the-css-you-chose" appropriately.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{"css/the-css-you-chose.css" | absURL}}" rel="stylesheet" id="theme-stylesheet"> 
    <script src="{{ "js/highlight.pack.js" | absURL }}"></script>
    <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

You can follow [Amber Thomas' blog](https://amber.rbind.io/blog/2017/11/15/syntax-highlighting/) for more information.